# How to Show Apple Wallet without Apple Pay — Boarding Passes Only (iOS 10)

Tags: ios, screen-lock, wallet

In Australia, Apple Pay is not widely supported, so the credit card facility is not of much use at this time. On the other hand, the two major domestic airlines certainly support Apple Wallet with their boarding passes.

The question is:

(a) Is it possible to hide the credit card section, or, at least, to move it below the boarding passes?
(b) Is this why the double-click short cut doesn’t work to show the Wallet from the lock screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For devices supporting Apple Pay, the feature cannot be disabled and is shown at the top of the Wallet app. There is no option to hide the feature or disable it using Restrictions.

Double-clicking the home button only works if there is a card in Apple Pay, upon which the default Apple Pay card is shown and other Wallet cards/passes can be presented. Unfortunately without any Apple Pay card this feature is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround to Apple Pay in Wallet, if you only want to show a boarding pass... (This is a slightly different answer from the one above. I didn't turn off/disable Apple Pay - I just got around it.)

I was presented by the (un-dismissable) "Pay with Touch ID..." message. I couldn't expose the full boarding pass (which was partially shown on the screen.) Swiping up, left, right didn't work.

BUT... **tapping on the boarding pass** moves it into view. (Duh! Whew!)

Comment: I’m confused as to how this is a workaround, this just appears to be the standard way of using Wallet? You’re meant to tap a pass to display it, whether you’re using Apple Pay or not

Comment: Yeah, well... I was completely distracted by "Pay with Touch ID" which was, to my (old guy's) mind a modal dialog, inhibiting all interaction. That's what I observed after trying swipes all directions to no effect. I have now added a tap to my "standard suite of gestures".  I enter this as a "workaround" so that this appears somewhere on the intertubes. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that makes sense, perhaps Apple ought to add the swipe up gesture throughout Wallet to get to the passes at the bottom alongside the swipe down or tap

Answer (score 0):

The Wallet contains every virtual card or pass you have but it is meant to be location-aware so that it can offer the appropriate card/pass when you need it.   Check Privacy -> Location Services -> Wallet to see if you are allowing the Wallet app to access your location.

I have many cards cards & passes in the Wallet app.  If I am standing in an airport and location services is enabled for Wallet, then the phone's lock screen typically has a Wallet notice that I can tap to immediately open the boarding pass.